# Oracle APEX 20.1.x Data Load Wizard date format issue

Tags: datetime, oracle-apex

In Apex 20.1.x I create an app to import in a table from an XLS. To do so I use the Create Data Load Wizard that add the 4 pages needed for the import.
The whole process work correctly and no exceptions are raised.
The problem is that in some case a field datetime is formatted in different ways (eg. 02/10/2020 00:18:15 -> 20-10-02 00:18:15) due to different pc/browser (?). I need to understand which setup or config (maybe App Properties -> Globalization?) inspect in order to investigate the issue.

*** EDITED after comment ***
I try Trasformation Rule with replace but it does't work. I am trying with PlSQL Expression in order to use a DB function or procedure to work on my format but several errors occurs.
With syntax myprocedure(:myFildName) the rule is not saved because it seems to requires a function.
Using the syntax myfunction(:myFieldName) the rule is savaed but during import a generic "Processing error" message is shown
The documentation on this is quite poor.

Answer (score 0):

If the different date formats occur in the import file, you could try to use a transformation rule for your data load definition: `Application | Shared Components | Data Load Definitions` pick your data load definition and go to `Transformation Rules` and create one, for example of the type `Replace`.